# make tkhtmlview HTMLLabel resize to fit the text

Tags: python, html, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a subtitles renderer and to display the subtitles I'm using tkhtmlview.HTMLLabel because some subtitles contain html like `<i></i>` and so on.

The problem is its size is fixed and doesn't fit the content properly, so sometimes the text is too long and overflows outside the label, or it's too short and leaves me with a mostly empty label:

[image: mostly empty label]

## Code:

```py
import pysrt
import threading
from time import sleep
from ctypes import windll
from tkinter import Tk
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
from htmlBuilder.tags import P
from htmlBuilder.attributes import Style


should_quit = False


def play_subtitles(label: HTMLLabel):
    subtitles = pysrt.open("subtitles.srt")
    style = Style(
        color="white", 
        text_align="center", 
        font_size="25px", 
        font_family="Helvetica"
    )

    for line in subtitles:
        if should_quit:
            break

        html = P((style,), line.text)

        label.set_html(html.render())
        sleep(line.duration.seconds)


windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

root = Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x75+0+{int(screen_height - (screen_height * 0.12))}")
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "grey")
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
root.config(bg="grey")
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: root.destroy())

label = HTMLLabel(root, background="black", borderwidth=0)
label.pack()

t = threading.Thread(target=play_subtitles, args=(label,))
t.start()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()

should_quit = True
t.join()
```

How do I make the label fit the text perfectly?